# PHP function to loop thru a string and replace characters for all possible combinations

Tags: php

I am trying to write a function that will replace characters in a string with their HTML entity encoded equivalent.

I want it to be able to go through all the possible combinations for the given string, for example:

- go one-by-one
- then combo i.e.. 2 at a time, then three at a time, till you get length at a time
- then start in combo split, i.e.. first and last, then first and second to last
- then first and last two, fist and second/third last

So for the characters "`abcd`" it would return:

```
&#97;bcd
a&#98;cd
ab&#99;d
abc&#100;
&#97;&#98;cd
a&#98;&#99;d
ab&#99;&#100;
&#97;&#98;&#99;d
a&#98;&#99;&#100;
&#97;&#98;&#99;&#100;
&#97;bc&#100;
&#97;b&#99;d
```

etc.......... so on and so forth till there are no other combinations

Any ideas, or has anyone seen a function somewhere I could modify for this purpose?

Comment: What the heck could you possibly need this for?

Comment: This smells like a terribly inefficient way to do something... If you tell us what you are trying to accomplish, then maybe we can suggest something entirely different.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, doing this is essentially an invitation to a DOS attack unless the string size is limited.

Comment: it is for encoding a url, in that it has to be unique each time. yes if it was on a public server it would be a perfect invitation for a DOS attack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

loop from 0 to 2^length - 1. On each step, if Nth bit of the loop counter is 1, encode the Nth character

```
$str = 'abcd';

$len = strlen($str);

for($i = 0; $i < 1 << $len; $i++) {
    $p = '';
    for($j = 0; $j < $len; $j++)
        $p .= ($i & 1 << $j) ? '&#' . ord($str[$j]) . ';' : $str[$j];
    echo $p, "\n";
}
```

Comment: +1 Oooh sexy (if a little hard to follow without the accompanying comment)

Comment: Thats very nice too!! I wish you could do a split decision here, because I could spend all day going back and forth between yours and konforce

Answer (score 1):

There are `2^n` combinations, so this will get huge fast. This solution will only work as long as it fits into PHP's integer size. But really who cares? A string that big will print so many results you'll spend your entire life looking at them.

```
<?php
$input = 'abcd';

$len = strlen($input);
$stop = pow(2, $len);

for ($i = 0; $i < $stop; ++$i)
{
  for ($m = 1, $j = 0; $j < $len; ++$j, $m <<= 1)
  {
    echo ($i & $m) ? '&#'.ord($input[$j]).';' : $input[$j];
  }
  echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: I like it, yes it will run out of memory space eventually, but by then it will have generated plenty of combinations that will do the job

Answer (score 0):

How about [this](http://www.ideone.com/xI7cG)?

```
<?php
function permutations($str, $n = 0, $prefix = "") {
   if ($n == strlen($str)) {
      echo "$prefix\n";
      return;
   }

   permutations($str, $n + 1, $prefix . $str[$n]);
   permutations($str, $n + 1, $prefix . '&#' . ord($str[$n]) . ';');
}

permutations("abcd");
?>
```